# Mathematical variable in Processing

Tags: processing

I want to make a background with changing color on each point of the window depending on the distance of that point from the center of the window in Processing. All I need is a variable to designate x and y coordinates of the screen. How can I do that?

Now, I tried to define such a variable in Processing but failed to do so. But, I've written this code with built-in variables mouseX and mouseY. This is the code I've written:

```
void setup(){
 size(640,360);
 frameRate(144);
}

void draw(){
  int x=0;
  int y=0;
  x=x+1;
  y=y+1;
  float d=dist(width/2,height/2, mouseX,mouseY);
  float maxd=dist(width/2,height/2, width,height);
  float colour=map(d,0,maxd,0,255);
 stroke(50,20,30);
 strokeWeight(2);
 for(x=0; x<width; x=x+20){
  for(y=0; y<height; y=y+20){
    rect(x,y,20,20);
    fill(colour);
  }
 }
}
```

and it works perfectly as I expected. Now, all I need is some variables (like mathematical variables which change the values within some defined range) to specify the coordinates of each point on the screen. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already doing most of what you've described with this nested `for` loop:

```
for(x=0; x<width; x=x+20){
  for(y=0; y<height; y=y+20){
```

This nested `for` loop creates `x` and `y` variables that iterate over every point in the frame.

From here, you could use those variables to calculate a color. Here's a simplified example:

```
for(x=0; x<width; x=x+20){
  for(y=0; y<height; y=y+20){
    fill(x, y, 0);
    rect(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
 }
```

This code now uses the `x` and `y` variables directly in the calculation of the `fill` color.

From here, you could add logic that calculates a color based on the distance between `0,0` and `x,y`. You already have most of that logic as well, but you need to move it to be inside this nested `for` loop.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/for-loops) is a tutorial on `for` loops, and [here](https://happycoding.io/examples/processing/for-loops/) are some examples that use `for` loops, including examples that draw a different color at each point.

Comment: Thanks. From you answer, I learned a few things. I have had a pretty bad experience in StackOverflow. Your help will make me ask questions again. Otherwise, I would never have asked any question again.